# how can i expose MULE to external world?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component, mule-cluster

we are using an ESB for any communication between the external world and our application environment, for its obvious uses .
  i would like to understand , how can i make any call coming from the external world to go through the mule and vice versa. 
  what i mean is ,can i use a DNS which reroute all the calls coming form external world to MULE or can directly expose MULE as a service to the 
  external world so that  mule will call an required implementation and sends the response .

i would like to know is there any other way i can handle this .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mule ESB it's production ready. It is very common to find it directly exposed to internet (of course with the proper security measurements any kind of deployment should follow).

Depending on the needs you could even find it behind nginx or apache proxies, behind MOM's and others.